# FileList loses it's contents when passed via resolve() of Promise

Tags: javascript

Tested on Google Chrome version 80.0.3987.132 (this code doesn't work on some browsers)

Note: I am not looking for advice on how to make my code work (it works after the change I mention in the end), I'm just curious about the strange behavior of the not working code.

I wrote the following code to select files for upload, and got strange output:

```
var fileSelectorResolve;
var fileSelector = document.createElement('input');
fileSelector.setAttribute('type', 'file');

fileSelector.addEventListener('input', function() {
   console.log(this.files);
   fileSelectorResolve(this.files);
   fileSelectorResolve = null;
   fileSelector.value = '';
});

function selectFiles(multiple = false) {
   if(fileSelectorResolve) {
      fileSelectorResolve();
      fileSelectorResolve = null;
   }
   if(multiple){
      fileSelector.setAttribute('multiple', '');
   } else {
      fileSelector.removeAttribute('multiple');
   }
   return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      fileSelectorResolve = resolve;
      fileSelector.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
   });
}

async function testUpload(){
   const files = await selectFiles(true);
   console.log(files);
}
```

The console output of `testUpload()` was surprizing:

```
FileList {0: File, 1: File, length: 2}
FileList {length: 0}
```

The first line of output is from the event listener, and the second line is from `testUpload()`. The `FileList` object reached the `testUpload` function but somehow lost it's contents on the way.

When I replaced the event listener with this (putting the files into an array before passing on) everything worked properly:

```
fileSelector.addEventListener('input', function() {
   const files = [];
   for(file of this.files){
      files.push(file);
   }
   console.log(files);
   fileSelectorResolve(files);
   fileSelectorResolve = null;
   fileSelector.value = '';
});
```

Console output:

```
(2) [File, File]
(2) [File, File]
```

The code also worked properly when I passed the `FileList` object to other functions not via a Promise, so it seems to be related to whatever happens when the Promise is resolved.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Comment: i'd avoid promises for events.

Comment: @DanielA.White why avoid it here? this is the only way I know of for conveniently getting a list of files via a function call. The only alternative I can think of is using callbacks, which would be less convenient (and in some cases would require splitting functions into the parts before and after the file selection)

Comment: why not read the values as you need them? like on the submit event?

Comment: This function is intended to upload files with ajax. After the user clicks a button, a file dialog opens and then the files are immediately uploaded.

Comment: so then do all of that in your `input` handler

Comment: I have a few different file upload functions (for sending additional different data and to different URLs) in the same page, so that would require changing the event handler every time, and copying the same code to all the handlers. Or storing FormData on a global variable, and a callback function for post-request stuff (again, splitting functions around the file selection part) What is your reason not to use promises for events?